# Drools 4.X vs Drools 7.x performance

Tags: drools, kie

I'm migrating legacy drools files from 4.0.3 to 7X.
I have performance issue using new version. Of course, there a bunch of changes between these versions, so I decided to make dummy test and made JMH benchmarks for each version.
Here is complete code of two projects : [Github code](https://github.com/ditogam/droolsbenchmark.git)

I made two classes:

```
public class Subscriber {
        private int chargingProfileId;
        private List<Account> accounts;
public class Account {
    private int accountKindId;
    private long balance;
```

and generated drl with rundom criteria like this

```
rule "general.test.rule.cpX.acc.Y"
    activation-group "main"
    salience Z
    when
        Subscriber(chargingProfileId == X)
        $acc:Account(accountKindId == Y, balance>0)
    then
        $acc.decrementBalance();
end
```

All rules has ***salience*** in definition (sadly in legacy app we used a lot this feature). We need only StatelessSessions so only one rule has to activated per execute (activation-group "main").
I'm pregenerated dummy random data and saved in json file (subscribers.json) , so the data is exactly the same for both version tests. also rules are the same (count of rules is 4K ).

In drools 4X we are using java 1.6. We are using RuleBaseConfiguration  with configuration:

```
conf.setSequential(false);
conf.setShadowProxy(false);
```

if ShadowProxy is enabled, Throughput decreeses dramatically:

```
Benchmark             (shadowProxy)   Mode  Cnt       Score      Error  Units
DroolsBenchmark.send          false  thrpt   30  138888.339 ± 6603.057  ops/s
DroolsBenchmark.send           true  thrpt   30    1704.062 ±  178.104  ops/s
```

I know, in new versions Drools do not uses ShadowProxy parameter, so there is no way to configure this in 7X.

```
RuleBaseConfiguration conf = (RuleBaseConfiguration)   KnowledgeBaseFactory.newKnowledgeBaseConfiguration();
conf.setSequential(false);
```

and the JMH output is

```
DroolsBenchmark.send  thrpt   30  67881.788 ± 941.384  ops/s
```

In real project setting conf.setSessionPoolSize(X); made better results, but sadly this not helped in this tests.
But when I set for  SessionPoolSize (in real tests), it seems that FireAllRulesCommand's  AgendaFilter fires several times per execution, even thought there is "activation group main":

```
    batch.add(new FireAllRulesCommand(match -> {
        RuleImpl rule = (RuleImpl) match.getRule();
        String activationGroup = rule.getActivationGroup();
        if (activationGroup != null && activationGroup.equals("main")) {
            RULE_FOUND_COUNT.incrementAndGet();
        }
        return true;
    }));
```

Sadly, I couldn't reproduce this in TestCase, I think because real project rules are more complicated, not dummy as this test.
Also tried to make KieBase(RuleBase in 4.x) as threadLocal, but this didn't helped, saw more degradation...

In real project I have ~15K ops/s with drools 4.x and only ~2.5K ops/s with 7.x.
I used several versions of drools 7.X (7.52.0.Final, 7.59.0.Final, 7.52.0.Final-redhat-00008 ...), but nearly the same problem.

Of course, it's different versions, also with unsupported java and drools, also JMH versions are different (1.6.3 for java 1.6 and 1.32 for java 8). I know, drools improved greatly during these period, but the results shows my problem.

I was testing JMH with

```
@BenchmarkMode(Mode.Throughput)
@OutputTimeUnit(TimeUnit.SECONDS)
```

I change it to to see latencies

```
@BenchmarkMode(Mode.AverageTime)
@OutputTimeUnit(TimeUnit.MICROSECONDS)
```

but results are the same. In my example ,drools 4.0.3 has nearly 2X performance compare to 7.52.0.Final .
There is "jmsoutput" in each project and you'll see the results
drools 4.0.3 final results:

```
Result: 75.845 ±(99.9%) 2.668 us/op [Average]
  Statistics: (min, avg, max) = (68.360, 75.845, 87.189), stdev = 3.994
  Confidence interval (99.9%): [73.176, 78.513]


# Run complete. Total time: 00:05:51

Benchmark             Mode  Cnt   Score   Error  Units
DroolsBenchmark.send  avgt   30  75.845 ± 2.668  us/op
```

drools 7.52.0.Final results:

```
Result "com.drools.perf.test.DroolsBenchmark.send":
  147.362 ±(99.9%) 2.510 us/op [Average]
  (min, avg, max) = (140.884, 147.362, 157.948), stdev = 3.757
  CI (99.9%): [144.852, 149.872] (assumes normal distribution)
# Run complete. Total time: 00:05:52
Benchmark             Mode  Cnt    Score   Error  Units
DroolsBenchmark.send  avgt   30  147.362 ± 2.510  us/op
```

What is the problem? I think it's kind of configuration ...

Comment: Please share your benchmark on GitHub, there are so many differences between 4 and 7 that is totally not obvious

Comment: Hi Luka. I posted whole 2 projects on https://github.com/ditogam/droolsbenchmark . Each project contains jmsoutput file with result. I know there is lot performance improvent, Just wanted to know what I''m doing wrong and get that performance

Comment: As a side note, your Drools 7 version isn't actually threadsafe so hopefully you're not loading your rules like this in your production version.

Comment: Are you benchmarking the `main` method or just the rules execution part? Eg. is your timing being skewed by the compile/load time of the rules?

Comment: @RoddyoftheFrozenPeas Yes, it's not in production , I'm just testing. I'm precompiling dules and saving it in "rools.data" file (See DroolsHelper compile). DroolsBenchmark is JMH runner, you can run it with test or main. benchmark calls DroolsHelper.executeSubscriber, which will load packages once (synchronized on class). I just corrected DroolsHelper.ruleBase(), made it synchronized. So very few executions will be synchronized in warmup phase, all others will use RULE_BASE constant.

Comment: About threadsafety . I saw some benchmarks on https://github.com/kiegroup/kie-benchmarks/tree/main/drools-benchmarks. You are using DisposeSessionWithProcessRuntimeBenchmark on timeFactsInsertionAndRulesFiringStateless method and you do not synchronize anything. As I saw , you use reintrantlocks during executions, so it's wrapped for new instance of StatelessKnowledgeSessionImpl which uses statefullsession instance with internalCreateStatefulKnowledgeSession (if not pool ise used). Can you share some good examples using stateless session in multithreaded enviroment?

Comment: Hi, I tried to remove $acc.decrementBalance(), to check out if there is some kind of Reactive behave tried to reevaluate rules (even thought it's not "modify" or "update" statement, also salience combination with activation group has to guarantee rules evaluation only once in a group). But got nearly the same result. Also, about thread safety, if it's not threadsafe, then there should not be nor synchronization, non lock overhead, so execution time should be better. Can you please explain "Drools 7 version isn't actually threadsafe". Do you mean there is other library with threadsafty ? Thanks

Comment: Each time I run your Drools 7 benchmark, the performance degrades further. I think there's a problem with your test harness. My first run matched your numbers, but by number 3 I'm down to `DroolsBenchmark.send  avgt   30  317.335 ± 5.099  us/op`.

Comment: Hi. Of course performance metrics are very, depends on hardware, kernel, java version, system load ... I made little changes to project renamed it to DroolsBenchmarkTest, so you can run with mvn clean -Dtest=DroolsBenchmarkTest test. But logic stays the same. There is 100K data, benchmark loops thought array, if index exceeds size, rotates index to 0 . On my home desktop, run Drools4, then Drools7 several times. Nearly the same results. Drools4 always >2X performance (java 8,11,17 different vendors, gc algorithms). Also run it on some servers, the same difference.

Comment: I just commited Flamegraph generated with AsyncProfiler(look at flamegraphs dir in Drools7 ), in WithUUID.html you'll see nearly 16% of time spend in ContextImpl's constructor, so, there is very hight synchronization on "/dev/(u)random". Tried to copy this class to my project and replace static AtomicLong's incrementAndGet to make name unique, got little improvement.

Comment: Also managed to run Drools 4.0.3 with Java 11 and 17. Performance lowed nearly the same as for Drools 7. I think it's because of a lot of "synchronized" blocks.I think  it's because of nodern java is optimized for atomics and different lock types then synchronized. In Drools 4.0.3 UseParallelGC (which is not acceptable for our user case) and UseShenandoahGC(Amazon dand Microsoft builds) got nearly same performance : ~130K vs ~100K. ZGC lowered it to 48-53K and G1 ~75K.